# table starting unnecessarily in a new page

Tags: tables

Hi every time I try to draw a table if the space left is not enough it doesn't start in the actual page and continue on the next it starts in the next page leaving a huge space in the previous page like this:
[image]

here is my code :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Les modules de la phase d'enquête.}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|>{\columncolor{green!20}}p{5cm}|p{6cm}|}
\hhline{~|--|}
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{Modules} & \textbf{Actions} \\ \hline
 & Vérification   des processus & Evaluer   les processus mises en place pour maintenir la posture de sécurité du système   actuelle. \\
\hhline{~|--|}
 & Vérification   de la configuration & Evaluer   les opérations de la cible, puis les comparer aux besoins opérationnels de   l’organisation. \\
\hhline{~|--|}
& Validation   de la propriété & Vérification   des logiciels sans licence ou applications illégales au sein de la cible. \\
\hhline{~|--|}
& Contrôle   de ségrégation & Tente   d’identifier les informations personnelles sur le système et la mesure dans   laquelle les informations peuvent être accessibles par des utilisateurs   non-autorisés. \\
\hhline{~|--|}
& Vérification   de l’exposition & Identification   des informations disponibles sur internet concernant le système cible. \\
\hhline{~|--|}
\multirow{-7.9}{*}{\textbf{Phase d’initiation}} & Repérage   de renseignements concurrentiels & Identifie   les informations public ou accessibles qui pourraient avoir un effet négatif   sur le propriétaire de la cible par des moyens externes ou concurrentiels. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: That is by design. The only purpose of the `table` environment is to allow the table to move to stop bad white space at page breaks. However you are using `[H]` which disables that.

Comment: so should I take away the [H]

Comment: try `[htbp]` to start with

Comment: it changes the position of the tables by keeping in them in the same order but to the last

Comment: if  by "to the last" you mean it goes to the last page then not usually it depends on lots of factors, the `h` in `htbp` means it first tries to place it without moving, then it will try t ie top of the next page. see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats?tab=Votes

Comment: As already mentioned, a `table` environment can't be split acorss pages. You would need the `longtable` package for that. Personally, I would not recommend splitting a table that would easily fit onto a single page across pages, though, especially not since your particular table contains a `multirow` spanning many rows in the first column. Using longtable with such a table can be tricky as the contents of the multirow can end up overlapping with the footer of a page.

Comment: If you don't want your table to float and you also don't want th large white space at the end of the previous page, you could probably make sure the table takes up less vertical space. You could do so by reducing the widths of the first two columns quite significantly, as they currently contain quite a lot of "wasted" white space. Probably you're lucky ad the adjusted table fits onto the previous page withut leaving a large gap and without the need to split it.

Comment: You could also consider getting rid of the first column entirely. The information "Phase d’initiation" is already contained in the table's caption (at least in the screenshot), so no need to repeat it inside of the table. This could help you save even more space.

Answer (score 1):

The `[H]` option will place the (non)float exactly “here”. So, if there is not enough space left on the page for accommodating the object, it will be moved to the next page.

The best is to pass something like `[!htp]` and to worry about the placement only when the document is in its final form as regards to the text.

I suggest also an alternative way to typeset the table, but “Phase d'initiation” should not be on a column by itself in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,caption}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Les modules de la phase d'enquête.}
\label{tab:my-table}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  >{\hsize=0.75\hsize\columncolor{green!20}\RaggedRight}X
  >{\hsize=1.25\hsize}X
}
\hline
\rowcolor{white}\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Phase d'initiation}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Modules} & \textbf{Actions} \\
\hline
Vérification des processus &
  Evaluer les processus mises en place pour maintenir la posture de sécurité
  du système actuelle.
\\
Vérification de la configuration &
  Evaluer les opérations de la cible, puis les comparer aux besoins opérationnels
  de l’organisation.
\\
Validation de la propriété &
  Vérification des logiciels sans licence ou applications illégales au sein de la cible.
\\
Contrôle de ségrégation &
  Tente d’identifier les informations personnelles sur le système et la mesure dans
  laquelle les informations peuvent être accessibles par des utilisateurs non-autorisés.
\\
Vérification de l’exposition &
  Identification des informations disponibles sur internet
  concernant le système cible.
\\
Repérage de renseignements concurrentiels &
  Identifie les informations public ou accessibles qui pourraient avoir un effet négatif
  sur le propriétaire de la cible par des moyens externes ou concurrentiels.
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\kant[3]

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Les modules de la phase d'enquête.}
\label{tab:my-table-notabular}

\newcommand{\moduleaction}[2]{\textit{#1}\\#2\\}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Phase d'initiation}}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Module}}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Action}\\
\midrule
\moduleaction{Vérification des processus}{%
  Evaluer les processus mises en place pour maintenir la posture de sécurité
  du système actuelle.
}
\addlinespace
\moduleaction{Vérification de la configuration}{%
  Evaluer les opérations de la cible, puis les comparer aux besoins opérationnels
  de l’organisation.
}
\addlinespace
\moduleaction{Validation de la propriété}{%
  Vérification des logiciels sans licence ou applications illégales au sein de la cible.
}
\addlinespace
\moduleaction{Contrôle de ségrégation}{%
  Tente d’identifier les informations personnelles sur le système et la mesure dans
  laquelle les informations peuvent être accessibles par des utilisateurs non-autorisés.
}
\addlinespace
\moduleaction{Vérification de l’exposition}{%
  Identification des informations disponibles sur internet
  concernant le système cible.
}
\addlinespace
\moduleaction{Repérage de renseignements concurrentiels}{%
  Identifie les informations public ou accessibles qui pourraient avoir un effet négatif
  sur le propriétaire de la cible par des moyens externes ou concurrentiels.
}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\kant[5-6]

\end{document}
```

The `kantlipsum` package just provides mock text to show the tables in context.

[image]